# stack trace from the current location in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-standard

How can I constructs a stack trace from the current location?

In .NET 4.5 works this solution:

```
System.Diagnostics.StackTrace stackTrace = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(true);
for (int i = 0; i < stackTrace.FrameCount; ++i)
{
    System.Diagnostics.StackFrame frame = stackTrace.GetFrame(i);
    MethodBase callerMethod = frame.GetMethod();
    ...
}
```

But what is the solution in .NET Core?
The constructor `public StackTrace(bool fNeedFileInfo)` does not exists anymore.

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE** .NET Standard 2.0 has been released and the constructor is in there as promised.

---

It seems like this type is at the moment not available. In [this post](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/1797) it is mentioned that it will be added to .net standard 2.0.

You could use the [`System.Diagnostics.StackTrace`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Diagnostics.StackTrace/) nuget package which supports .net core 5.0, .net standart 1.3 and more

Or you could use the [`master`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Diagnostics.StackTrace/ref/System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.cs) branch of .net core.

Comment: Thanks, I will be waiting for .net standard 2.0 https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Diagnostics.StackTrace/ref/System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.cs

Comment: fyi the `StackTrace` type is already available for 1.0 via the `System.Diagnostics.StackTrace` nuget package but no constructor allowing to create a new trace - only for caught exceptions. There's also `Environment.StackTrace` but it only gives a pre-rendered string.